# the emotion that the subject agreed and that was being expressed

Tags: grammar

> For each photograph, the emotion that the subjects agreed was being
> expressed was the emotion that the person photographed was, in fact,
> feeling.

Thank you for your attention. Could someone help me parse out the grammar of this part "**the emotion that the subjects agreed was being expressed** [...] "? And what's the usage/reduced form called?

if I unravel the reduced form, does this part mean: "the emotion that the subject agreed and that was being expressed ..."?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Presumably this describes an experiment to see whether people can recognise emotions from facial expressions. For each photograph, the subjects (of the experiment) agreed with one another what emotion was being expressed, and they were always correct.